# Analytical solutions to integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, physics

While calculating the magnetic field at an arbitrary point due to a charged sphere rotating about the z-axis, I came upon the following integral,

$$\iiint\frac{x^3\cos^2{\theta}\left[\left(c-x\sin{\theta}\right)\left(\cos{\phi}\hat{x}+\sin{\phi}\hat{y}\right)+\left(x\cos{\theta}-b\sin{\phi}-a\cos{\phi}\right)\hat{z}\right]}{\left[a^2+b^2+c^2-2x\left(a\cos{\theta}\cos{\phi}+b\cos{\theta}\sin{\phi}+c\sin{\theta}\right)+x^2\right]^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx\,d\theta\,d\phi$$

Here $a\hat{x}+b\hat{y}+c\hat{z}$ is the position vector of the arbitrary point at which the field is calculated.

I tried all the possible substitutions I know but none seem to work. By the look of it I do not think an analytic solution even exists. I even tried to look for numerical methods to solve integrals on the web but did not find anything useful.

I would like to know how to numerically calculate such integrals or what software/website to use since Wolframalpha did not turn out to be very useful.

Also is there a way to tell just by looking at an equation whether an analytic solution exists or not?

I also do not understand why the solution to such a simple problem turn out to be this hard to compute? By simple I refer to the fact that this problem basically deals with classical physics and contains none of the heavy mathematical principles of QFT or GR and also there is a nice spherical symmetry associated to it.

Comment: Welcome to the site !

Comment: Regarding how monstrous the integral is, I doubt if anyone would spend time on it.

Comment: @Szeto Yes i know that. I don't mind not getting explicit solutions but it would help if i were to be recommended websites/free softwares that i could use to numerically compute the integral or it would help even if someone gave me the list of relevant concepts and techniques that i need to learn in order to tackle problems of this kind on my own. I added the integral to the question to make it easy for people to recommend appropriate softwares etc.

Comment: It looks like you can do the $x$ integral which would make any subsequent numerical integration easier. What are the integration limits of $x$? Also, have you looked at special points like $a=b=0$ and maybe $c$ very large. The integration may be possible then and you can then check that your expression for the field is in line with what you expect for this simpler system.

Comment: @user121049 The x limits vary from 0 to R which is the radius of the sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can actually be solved analytically, although it is not exactly straightforward. An important part to obtain the solution, is choosing a suitable reference frame that simplifies the computation.

Since the problem is symmetric under rotations about the $z$-axis, you can choose the point $(a,b,c)$ to lie in the $xz$-plane, effectively eliminating $b$ from the integral. With that in mind and considering the current of the rotating charges about the $z$-axis, Ampere's law will tell you that the magnetic field will have no azimuthal component, and hence that for $b=0$ there will be no $\hat{y}$-contribution in the magnetic field. Also, using spherical rather than cartesian coordinates is helpful.

Assuming the result you provided is correct, it is not impossible to perform the integral, but it is not convenient. A simpler approach is to compute the vector potential $\vec{A}(r,\theta,\phi)$ of a spherical shell with constant charge density. Use that result to integrate over the full sphere, and finally use $\vec{B}=\nabla \times \vec{A}$ to obtain the result.

The derivation of a rotating homogeneously charged spherical shell can be found for instance in "Introduction to electrodynamics" by David J. Griffiths, Example 5.11 ( I am sure you can find the book).

The result for a rotating homogeneously charged sphere of radius $R$, charge $Q$, and angular velocity $\omega$ is
$$
\vec{B}(r,\theta)= \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \frac{Q R^2 \omega}{5 r^3} (2 \cos \theta ~\hat{r} + \sin \theta ~ \hat{\theta})
$$
with $r \geq R$.

Is there a way to tell wether there exists an analytic solution? The short answer is NO, you can only try to find one. In all honesty very few problems in physics have an analytic solution, but those that have are the ones you will typically encounter in all the courses and textbooks and basic courses. It is a misconception to assume that problems in classical physics are easier to solve. Consider for instance the "simple" problem of 3 point masses, which in general can not be solved analytically.

Comment: That was very helpful thankyou!